# Why does C name (link symbol) of the specific function should be prepended with 'pg_finfo_'?

Tags: c, postgresql

I have DLL with one function

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "fmgr.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one_float8);

Datum
add_one_float8(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    float8 arg = PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(0);
    PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(arg + 1.0);
}
```

When I try to create function:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION add_one(double precision) RETURNS double precision
   AS 'DIRECTORY\mylib.dll', 'add_one_float8'
   LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

I get error "ERROR:  could not find function "add_one_float8"" 
but with "pg_finfo_add_one_float8" create script ended successfully.

So is it normal to prepend function name with "pg_finfo_" or i do smth wrong?

PostgreSQL version 9.1

Thank you.

update:

makefile

```
PG_DIR=D:/Programs/PostgreSQL
PG_LIB=$(PG_DIR)/lib/postgres.lib
PG_INCLUDE_SERVER=$(PG_DIR)/include/server
PG_INCLUDE=$(PG_DIR)/include
PG_INCLUDE_PORT_WIN32=$(PG_DIR)/include/server/port/win32
PG_INCLUDE_PORT_WIN32_MSVC=$(PG_DIR)/include/server/port/win32_msvc
MSDK_INCLUDE="D:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include"
COMPILER_INCLUDES=/I$(PG_INCLUDE) /I$(PG_INCLUDE_SERVER) /I  $(PG_INCLUDE_PORT_WIN32) /I$(PG_INCLUDE_PORT_WIN32_MSVC) /I$(MSDK_INCLUDE) 

LINKER_DLL_FLAGS=/MACHINE:X86
COMPILER_DLL_FLAGS=/c /TC /D "WIN32"

DLL_NAME=mylib
DLL_DEST=D:\lib

OBJS=myfunc.obj

.c.obj:
    cl $(COMPILER_DLL_FLAGS) $(COMPILER_INCLUDES) $*.c  

all:$(OBJS)
    link -out:$(DLL_DEST)\$(DLL_NAME).dll /DLL $(OBJS) $(PG_LIB)
```

Comment: That's not normal, and something is certainly wrong. While the create script may've run successfully I'd be amazed if calling the function didn't just crash the backend. How did you compile this DLL? You're on Windows so you won't have just used pgxs like on sane platforms.

Comment: This function don't crash, but always returns smth like 4.9e-324.. that's true.I compile it in console with Microsoft Visual C++ compiler cl.exe as c-files and link with link.exe into dll

Comment: Ok, so you compiled it by hand. You should really show the command line(s) used in an update to your question. I won't be too surprised if you're missing necessary pre-processor definitions. Compiling extensions on Windows is a real pain. I usually do it by adding them to the PostgreSQL source tree in contrib/ and letting the vcbuild.pl code take care of building them. I'm not sure if you can use pgxs on windows...

Answer (score 2):

Building extensions on windows is a pain. I'm not sure if there's really any standard, recommended way to do it.

If you're compiling using `nmake` with a custom makefile, you'll need to provide appropriate compiler arguments.

Here's what `cl` is called with when building core code on my Windows box, using Windows SDK 7.1 with `setenv /x86 /release /xp`, all on one line:

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe  /c
>   /Isrc/include /Isrc/include/port/win32 /Isrc/include/port/win32_msvc
>
>   /I"D:\libs\x86\Release\zlib-1.2.7\include" /Isrc\backend /Zi /nologo 
>   /W3 /WX- /Ox /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D __WINDOWS__ /D __WIN32__
>
>   /D EXEC_BACKEND /D WIN32_STACK_RLIMIT=4194304  /D
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D BUILDING_DLL  /D _USE_32BIT_TIME_T /D _MBCS /GF /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS  /fp:precise
>   /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope  /Gd /TC /wd4018 /wd4244 /wd4273 /wd4102
>   /wd4090 /wd4267 /analyze- /errorReport:queue`

Contrib modules probably get somewhat different options; I haven't checked in detail. The point is that there are a lot of compiler flags - definitions, mostly - that are passed when building.

How I usually build modules on Windows is to build a copy of the PostgreSQL source tree with my module in the contrib/ directory, using the regular `build.pl` to compile it. I'm sure there's a more sensible way, I haven't needed to do it enough to bother looking.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!

this code works fine (source: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jacobson/cs122b/Project/06-CFunctions.html)

```
/* Use 32-bit timer (provided header file uses 64-bit timer, not
 * compatible with Windows postgreSQL versions */
#define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T

/* Ensure that Pg_module_function and friends are declared __declspec(dllexport) */
#ifndef BUILDING_MODULE
#define BUILDING_MODULE
#endif

#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"

/*--------------- BEGIN REDEFINITION OF PG MACROS -------------------* 
 These rewritten versions of PG_MODULE_MAGIC and PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1
 * declare the module functions as __declspec(dllexport) when building
 * a module. They also provide PGMODULEEXPORT for exporting functions
 * in user DLLs.
 */
#undef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
#undef PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1

#define PGMODULEEXPORT __declspec (dllexport)

#define PG_MODULE_MAGIC \
PGMODULEEXPORT const Pg_magic_struct * \
PG_MAGIC_FUNCTION_NAME(void) \
{ \
    static const Pg_magic_struct Pg_magic_data = PG_MODULE_MAGIC_DATA; \
    return &Pg_magic_data; \
} \
extern int no_such_variable

#define PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(funcname) \
PGMODULEEXPORT const Pg_finfo_record *  \
CppConcat(pg_finfo_,funcname) (void) \
{ \
    static const Pg_finfo_record my_finfo = { 1 }; \
    return &my_finfo; \
} \
extern int no_such_variable

/*--------------- END REDEFINITION OF PG MACROS -------------------*/

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one_float8);

PGMODULEEXPORT Datum add_one_float8(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    float8   arg = PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(0);
    PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(arg + 1.0);
}
```

You should only compile this code using `nmake` with a makefile above in a question and add the functions to the database via the CREATE FUNCTION command:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_one(double precision) RETURNS double precision
AS 'DIRECTORY\mylib.dll', 'add_one_float8'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

Comment: That'll work, but it's the wrong way to do it. You should *NOT* be re-defining `PG_MODULE_MAGIC`, etc, you should be setting appropriate pre-processor definitions to cause the ones you `#include` to behave correctly.

Comment: Craig, I tried compiler arguments you recommended, but it didn't work.. I can't find any other information about it, all examples are not for Windows.

Comment: I wasn't recommending passing those arguments exactly. I was showing you that when compiling the Pg sources additional flags are passed. Exactly which flags depend on your build. I strongly recommend that you build your extension in a PostgreSQL source tree in contrib/ using `build.pl`. I agree that building extensions for Windows is woefully under-documented.